# How to use .catch on pdf.js getDocument in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf.js

I have some code in javascript that I need to use in a Angular4 app, so I am converting it to typescript 2.4.2. I have a problem with this code.

In javascript this works fine:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(fileUrl).then(function (pdf) {
    if (pageNumber > pdf.numPages) pageNumber = pdf.numPages;
    return pdf.getPage(+pageNumber)
        .then(makeThumbnail)
        .then(saveToDisk)
})
.catch(console.error);
```

but when I convert it to type script:

```
    PDFJS.getDocument(fileName).then(pdf => {
        if (pageNumber > pdf.numPages) pageNumber = pdf.numPages;
        return pdf.getPage(+pageNumber)
            .then(this.makeThumbnail)
            .then(this.saveToDisk)
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

I get an error on the .catch "Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PDFPromise>'."
Why is that and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Correct a type definition for the library to specify right return Promise type or use `PDFJS.getDocument(fileName).promise.then()`

Comment: there is no official type definition library for 'pdfjs-dist' and looks like https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts#L30 specifies some imaginary PDFPromise type instead of ES6 Promise